# What's the difference between "mount -o sync" and "open" syscall with O_SYNC option

Tags: linux

"mount with sync option" and "open with O_SYNC option" both mean: All changes are immediately flushed to disk from buffer in kernel space.

So what's the difference?

Can "open" syscall option overrides "mount -o sync" option?

Comment: The open flag can override _not having_ `mount -o sync`. It's additive: If you have either one of the two, you get the behavior; so the global one is more general (applying not just to the one operation, but to _every_ operation against that filesystem).

Comment: It's surprising to me that the question is being asked; there's obvious value to both granular and global controls, and the context of each flag accurately implies that flag's scope.

Comment: I can't find any document on the internet compares them definitely, so I asked here.

Comment: You will rarely find any direct comparison in cases like this. Why? `mount` (mounts the entire filesystem) while `open` (opens a single file). The global/specific relationship is implied from the level of interaction each command has with the booted system. (though admittedly these types *forest-for-the-trees* issues are not apparent at first -- until you have experience with both)

Comment: Actually I also have another question. For stdout(fd 1), it's opened automatically, when "write" system call is used to write data to it, is the kernel buffer used? or the data is send to stdout directly?

Comment: stdout is **not** opened automatically. False premise. Its initial value is inherited from a parent; if it points anywhere but a TTY (and in most cases where it points to a TTY too), _someone_ in userspace originally opened it with an `open()` call and provided flags, and the child process inherits the descriptor with those flags and their effects intact.

Comment: If when you say "it's opened automatically" you mean the initial TTY handle provided by the kernel to the init process at boot time, O_SYNC is irrelevant there; a TTY is a character device, no block cache exists that applies to it in the first place